# Error trying to insert data with Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, request, laravel-5.1, relationships

I'm having a had time trying to insert data using Laravel 5.1

here's my code :

```
$event = Event::whereId($request->input('event'))->first();

$participant = new Participant([
    'email' => $request->input('mail'),
    'lastname' => $request->input('lastname'),
    'firstname' => $request->input('firstname'),
    'phonenumber' => $request->input('phone'),
    'address' => $request->input('address'),
    'department' => $request->input('department')
]);

$gender = Gender::whereId($request->input('gender'));
$expertise = Expertise::whereId($request->input('expertise'));
$country = Country::whereId($request->input('country'));

$participant->gender()->associate($gender);
$participant->expertise()->associate($expertise);
$participant->country()->associate($country);

$event->participant()->save($participant);
```

her's my error :

```
"Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string"
[...]
at BelongsToMany->save(object(Participant)) in EventController.php line 122
```

Line 122 correspond to : "$event->participant()->save($participant);"

I don't think you need any more information but you can always ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably an `Event` has many `Participants`.  If so, i believe the method on your `Event` model should be `participants()`, not `participant()`

```
$event->participants()->save($participant);
```

Comment: here's my "participant" relationship in my model "Event" :
    public function participant()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Participant');
    }

Answer (score 0):

To anyone coming here, here's how I solved it :

```
$gender = Gender::whereId($request->input('gender'))->first;
$expertise = Expertise::whereId($request->input('expertise'))->first;
$country = Country::whereId($request->input('country'))->first;
```

Comment: I'm assuming ID is the primary key for your `Gender`, `Expertise` and `Country` models?

To make it more readable, just do `$gender = Gender::find($request->input('gender');`